# Ctrl+Shift stopped working in Windows 7 on Logitech keyboard

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, logitech-keyboard

I've run into an issue with my Logitech Media Elite Keyboard. At some point layout changing in Windows 7 stopped working, and it was set up to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>, and I've figured out that this combo doesn't work anymore if I try to press both keys really simultaneously (i.e. word-by-word text selection with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Arrows</kbd> doesn't work now).

However, both <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> are working by themselves — <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, letter capitalization works. Furthermore, if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, then press <kbd>Shift</kbd> and then release <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, combo works and keyboard layout switches. And if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> and press cursor keys a few times being in text editor, cursor doesn't move until I release one of keys (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>). And if I press <kbd>arrows</kbd> "too many" times, the cursor starts moving in that direction infinitely after releasing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

I know it all looks very strange but it really is. I believe it to be not a hardware problem as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> occasionally work.

I think I was playing World of Tanks when it happened but I'm not sure. I don't know when exactly it happened.

I've tried putting my keyboard in different USB ports and in PS/2 as well, reinstalling drivers and installing Logitech SetPoint software — no luck.

Can anybody help and explain what happened to keyboard and why? And how to fix it, if possible.

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/681393/logitech-g110-keyboard-shift-s-is-broken?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow I pressed the “Favorites” button on the keyboard and didn't notice it; and button stuck and was “pressed” all the time. Now I've “released” it and keyboard works all right again

Comment: Great! Thanks for providing an answer for the community. :)