# Logitech G110 keyboard: Shift-S is broken

Tags: windows-7, logitech-keyboard

I got an Azerty (Belgian) Logitech G110. recently, my keyboard got the issue where my capital 'S' only works when I use Caps Lock. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> no longer does anything.

I noticed the problem starting on the 23rd, but it could originate earlier. it also occurs when using a selective start with only windows services enabled.

I installed the following software in the past month

- Adobe Reader XI
- Nvidia Driver 331.82
- Assassin's Creed IV
- Punkbuster (comes with the above game)
- Nvidia Virtual Audio 1.2.9
- Nvidia Geforce Experience 1.7.1
- Open AL
- Baldur's Gate: Enhanced Edition
- The secret World
- Torchlight 2
- PhysX 9.13

Any idea on what causes this and how to fix it?

Comment: When doing a selective start, also select the Logitech service. If that doesn't work, try launching `LGDCore.exe` as an administrator (Probably in `c:\program files (x86)\Logitech\...`). This doesn't appear to be an uncommon problem, and most solutions relate to upgrading the driver. In your case, the driver is probably fine, but disabling the service or startup registry sequence doesn't allow it's interpreter software to run automatically.

Comment: Considering you are a gamer, do you use any key re-mapping tool?

Comment: I don't use key remapping software apart from the Logitech Gaming software, and I installed that after I noticed the issue. and I cannot find the file mentioned by @matcarlson. I'll try to run the device manager driver update to see if that helps anything.

Comment: Update: it cannot find any more recent drivers for my keyboard.

Comment: I'd reinstall the driver package - Download it from [Logitech's site](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/support/gaming-keyboard-g110?osid=14&bit=64) or from Azerty. Logitech has a multilingual installer.

Comment: I suppose the name of the file may be different, considering it's from a differently named manufacturer (although the same, maybe different names/locations). Essentially Logitech's software won't load if Selective Start is enabled. You shouldn't be in that mode normally, though. If you run `services.msc` and look for either Azerty or Logitech, are the services running when in Selective Start? If you can't find it there, you can look in the registry (`regedit.exe` - look in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` for anything mentioning Azerty or Logitech).

Comment: I got a "Launch LCore" sZ in my registry, but I already installed the logitech gaming software when I noticed the issue as one of the first attempts to fix it. I find no driver mentions on their website, just the gaming software. and what is this Azerty website? all I can find is a supplyer, and I didn't buy my keyboard from them.